# Avoid having to cast with generics and a list of custom data

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have the following code for supporting a list of different types :

```
public enum eType
{
    tInt,
    tString,
    tDateTime
}

public interface ICustomType<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public abstract class DifferentType
{
    protected DifferentType(eType type, string mnemonic)
    {
        Type = type;
        Mnemonic = mnemonic;
    }

    public string Mnemonic { get; private set; }

    public eType Type { get; private set; }
}

public class DateTimeType : DifferentType, ICustomType<DateTime>
{
    public DateTimeType(DateTime value, string mnemonic)
        : base(eType.tDateTime, mnemonic)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public DateTime Value { get; private set; }
}

public class IntType : DifferentType, ICustomType<int>
{
    public IntType(int value, string mnemonic)
        : base(eType.tInt, mnemonic)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
}

public class StringType : DifferentType, ICustomType<string>
{
    public StringType(string value, string mnemonic)
        : base(eType.tString, mnemonic)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }
}

public static class UtilValue
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(DifferentType customType)
    {
        return ((ICustomType<T>)customType).Value;
    }
}

public class testTypes2
{
    public testTypes2()
    {
        var values = new List<DifferentType> { GetInt(), GetString(), GetDate() };

        foreach (var i in values)
        {
            switch (i.Type)
            {
                case eType.tInt:
                    int resInt = UtilValue.GetValue<int>(i);
                    break;

                case eType.tString:
                    string resString = UtilValue.GetValue<string>(i);
                    break;

                case eType.tDateTime:
                    DateTime resDateTime = UtilValue.GetValue<DateTime>(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTimeType GetDate()
    {
        return new DateTimeType(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), "MnemonicDate");
    }

    private IntType GetInt()
    {
        return new IntType(5, "MnemonicInt");
    }

    private StringType GetString()
    {
        return new StringType("ok", "MnemonicString");
    }
}
```

and would like to avoid the cast at line `return ((ICustomType<T>)customType).Value;` in the `UtilValue` class, any idea how I can get rid of that while still keeping the design?

I am not even sure if this cast is expensive to do? My guess is *most certainly*.

Comment: You should into a Visitor-pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern That should solve your problem and avoids the cast and the switch.

Comment: @lasseespeholt : Hi! This looks like an interesting idea, not sure how to implement it correctly though. I'll have to read the article a few times and play with the idea...thanks for the suggestion. If you could provide an answer with this idea, that would be awesome!

Comment: Now there is an example. The exact code depends on what you want to do in the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitor-pattern example:

```
interface IDifferentTypeVisitor
{
    void Visit(DateTimeType dt);
    void Visit(StringType st);
}

class DifferentType
{
    public abstract void Accept(IDifferentTypeVisitor visitor);
}

class DateTimeType : DifferentType
{
    public void Accept(IDifferentTypeVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

class StringType : DifferentType
{
    public void Accept(IDifferentTypeVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

class SomeVisitor : IDifferentTypeVisitor
{
    public void Visit(DateTimeType dt)
    {
        //DateTime resDateTime = dt.Value; Or similar
    }

    public void Visit(StringType st)
    {
        //string resString = st.Value; Or similar
    }
}

public class testTypes2
{
    public testTypes2()
    {
        var values = new List<DifferentType> { /* Content */ };
        var visitor = new SomeVisitor();

        foreach (var i in values)
        {
            i.Accept(visitor);
        }
    }
}
```

In C# 4 with `dynamic` it's possible to save some code by adding this to `DifferentType`:

```
public void Accept(IDifferentTypeVisitor visitor)
{
    visitor.Visit((dynamic)this);
}
```

and then delete all other `Accept` methods. It hurts performance but it looks better ;-)

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer! This is interesting, however I find it is a bit too restraining or maybe it is that I do not understand the concept correctly. I can only manipulate the custom datatype (ex. `DateTimeType`) within the visitor, how could I expose and use it within the test class (in the loop)?

Comment: @ibiza What do you want to do in the loop? Remember, you can always add state to the visitor.

Comment: I was thinking of manipulating the data (I modified your answer a bit for my purpose, each custom data has a Value property corresponding to its type, ex. `public DateTime Value { get; private set; }` for the `DateTimeType`) directly in the loop. As an example, I could have a `List<DateTime>` in the test class and want to add all the values that are of `DateTimeType` to that list.

Comment: @ibiza Then you just store the list in `SomeVisitor` and in the `Visit(DataTimeType)` you add the datetime to that list. In `testTypes2` you retrieve the list from the visitor with a method or a property.